# Kotlin Nullable JNI Type

Tags: kotlin, java-native-interface, nullable

How to work with **Kotlin nullable type** like '**Long?**', '**String?**' etc. on **JNI**?
JNI type signatures represent the following information:

```
Signature  |Java Type
-----------|----------------
    Z      | boolean
    B      | byte
    C      | char
    S      | short
    I      | int
    J      | long
    F      | float
    D      | double
    L      | fully-qualified-class;
    [ type | type[]
    (arg-types)| ret-type method type
```

But how I can use nullable '**var value:Long?**' from JNI?

Kotlin Code

```
class KtClass
{
    var value:Long? = null
}
```

JNI

```
jclass ktclass = env->FindClass("package/KtClass");
jmethodID ctorktID = env->GetMethodID(ktclass, "<init>", "()V");
env->NewObject(ktclass, ctorktID);

//J - mean Kotlin Long, but it not nullable 'Long?'
jfieldID valueID = env->GetFieldID(ktclass, "value", "J");
env->SetLongField(ktclass, valueID, NULL); //Error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Long?` becomes `java.lang.Long` on JVM, so use

```
env->GetFieldID(ktclass, "value", "Ljava/lang/Long;")
```